# What's the best way to create arrows in inkscape?

Tags: vector-graphics, inkscape

Adding arrows in inkscape using the line-ending option is quite limited.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers... will fix arrow color

This is a workaround that had to be introduced due to a limitation in SVG standard.

Answer (score 4):

The line ending is indeed quite limited, I noticed recently that changing the stroke colour does not change the ending colour, which is disappointing. I did however find a workaround, if you want to edit the arrows created by the line ending you could try converting the line to a path and then edit the arrows as a path, thus customizing them in any way you like.

I hope it helps.